# Shift+Backspace is Writing a Checkmark Symbol?

Tags: python, python-idle, backspace, ordinals

I can't even copy and paste a strange checkmark looking character from my IDLE interpreter session into this text field...I am running Linux Mint Julia, python version 2.6, but it also happens in 3.1. This occurs after holding the `shift` key and pressing `backspace`.

I tried doing this:

```
>>> ord('[strange-checkmark]')
8
```

Then running the reverse:

```
>>> chr(8)
\x08'
```

I'd really like to get this strange character to stop printing, and just delete the previous character instead.

I tried to recreate this character in `gedit`, `terminal`, and `chrome`. No luck. Searching for a ASCII chart of ordinal values calls this character `backspace`.

Here's an image from my session:

[image: A demonstration of printing the checkmark character, then passing it into the function ord()]

Comment: Does the character you see match what is shown for character 8 in [this table](http://www.ascii-codes.com/)?

Comment: No, it doesn't. I can't find a shot of one on a google image search, either. Is there a way to post an image here?

Comment: Yes, use the editor toolbar button that looks like an image frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a confirmed bug within Tkinter, and not necessarily IDLE.  See [Issue 1482122](http://bugs.python.org/issue1482122).

In brief:  If you want to fix it, you're welcome to try `xmodmap -e "keycode 22 = BackSpace"`, but you run the risk of no longer being able to issue a `Ctrl+Alt+Backspace` to kill your X Server.

<s>I can keep looking for more information into the bug; I'm not sure if the folks working on Tkinter have resolved this yet.</s>

**EDIT**:  Confirmed second source on issue - See [Linux%Shift-Backspace on the Tkinter Wiki](http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/Linux%25Shift-Backspace)